# How to retrieve date value from POST method?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following date input box in an HTML code:

```
<input type="date" name="DOB" size="20">
```

The form data are passed to a different PHP file using the POST method. And there the date is saved to a variable.

```
$DOB=$_POST['DOB'];
```

When I echo this variable it prints the date value saved in it. However if I use this variable in a query, the value won't be read. The query does not return any values.

This is my query:

```
"SELECT site_no, name,NIC,gender,address,telephone FROM employee WHERE emp_no=$emp_no AND DOB=$DOB"
```

Comment: never ever do this query , its open to sql injection and you could lose your all database

Comment: use single quotes DOB='$DOB'

Comment: Use single quote around `$DOB` in the query and if that will not work, then check the format of `$_POST['DOB']`. The format should be same as DB format i.e. `YYYY-mm-dd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

use single quotes with date(assumption you got date value in $DOB variable )

```
"SELECT site_no, name,NIC,gender,address,telephone FROM employee WHERE emp_no=$emp_no AND DOB='$DOB'"
```

**EDIT**

MySQL expects DATE and DATETIME literal values to be single-quoted as strings like '2001-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: It would be helpful if you added few notes on what you've changed. Without it it does not teach OP anything.

Comment: if you include why this doesnt work without single quote , it would be more informative

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose variables in single quotes. Use the code below

```
"SELECT site_no, name,NIC,gender,address,telephone FROM employee WHERE emp_no='$emp_no' AND DOB='$DOB'"
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: "You need to enclose variables in single quotes" --- that's not entirely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes for $DOB

```
  "SELECT site_no, name,NIC,gender,address,telephone FROM employee WHERE emp_no=$emp_no AND DOB='$DOB'"
```

Answer (score 0):

For visibility it's good practice to add quotes to your SQL. It's important to know what types you're working with and to escape the values, especially with something like this.
Your query with quotes and indentation for visibility:

```
SELECT 
    `site_no`, `name`, `NIC`, `gender`, `address`, `telephone` 
FROM 
    `employee` 
WHERE 
    `emp_no` = '$emp_no' 
AND
    `DOB` = '$DOB'
```

Best practice to save dates is either using DATE/DATETIME or timestamps. You'll want to verify the DOB format and input, strip unnecessary characters etc. Look up `real_escape_string`, `time` and `date` for PHP